# Multi condition to filter the document in mongodb according to subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to filter all documents by using multiple conditions.

```
{
    "name": "Maths",
    "excludeUserIds": [
        {
            "_id": 33,
            "groupIds": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Science",
    "excludeUserIds": [
        {
            "_id": 24,
            "groupIds": [
                "a",
                "x",
                "b"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Health",
    "excludeUserIds": []
},
{
    "name": "English",
    "excludeUserIds": [
        {
            "_id": 33,
            "groupIds": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The documents need to be returned if `excludeUserIds._id` not equal to given value **AND** `excludeUserIds.groupIds` are not in given array.
The mongo script I've written is

```
{
    "$match": {
      "excludeUserIds": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "_id": {
            $ne: 33
          },
          "groupIds": {
            $nin: [
              "a"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I expect this should return all document without **Maths**. But i doesn't work as I expected. Obviously I missed something. Thanks in advance. I created a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_diJrMPo5_Z)

Comment: check my edit and let me know.

Comment: Do you want to match `excludeUserIds.groupIds` with an array containing one element or could it also be multiple elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* the requirement is to return all subjects except Maths, your logic should be

> if excludeUserIds._id not equal to given value <s>AND</s> **OR** excludeUserIds.groupIds are not in given array.

Which can be translated to the following code, which convert the logic from `!A || !B` to the equivalent `!(A && B)` for shorter code.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      excludeUserIds: {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            _id: 33,
            groupIds: { $all: ["a"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OTI-yfhrHN5)

If you only need to match `excludeUserIds.groupIds` against one value, instead of an array, you can do the following

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      excludeUserIds: {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            _id: 33,
            groupIds: "a"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oOkb0c-tIv2)

Comment: Thanks u so much, you saved my day.

Comment: But how does OR work? I need to satisfy both conditions,

Comment: @Nishakar I think you got confused. If you want all courses except Maths, only one of the conditions needs to be satisfied. If both conditions must be satisfied, English would not get included because `_id` is `33` and  Science would not get included because it contains `"a"` in `groupIds`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "excludeUserIds": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "_id": {
            $ne: 33
          },
          "groupIds": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              $nin: [
                "a"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ThZBue-G6r)

You need to use `$elemMatch` for nested array as well.

**EDIT:**

[Updated Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LaCh1z6TgGu)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "excludeUserIds": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "_id": {
                $ne: 33
              },
              "groupIds": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                  $nin: [
                    "a"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              excludeUserIds: {
                $exists: false
              }
            },
            {
              excludeUserIds: null
            },
            {
              excludeUserIds: {
                $size: 0
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              "excludeUserIds.groupIds": {
                $exists: false
              }
            },
            {
              "excludeUserIds.groupIds": null
            },
            {
              "excludeUserIds.groupIds": {
                $size: 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You can check for existence/empty to get those as well.

Comment: Its only giving Science. In my case all subjects should be available except Maths

Comment: @Nishakar did you get a chance to check the update which I forgot to notify

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
db.collection.find({ 
   "excludeUserIds._id": { $ne: 33 }, 
   "excludeUserIds.groupIds": { $nin: ["a"] }
})
```

This is probably not the solution but will give required result.